# where to put JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

Tags: json, model-view-controller

i have this json returning line and i dont know where to put

```
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
       return new JsonResult()               
            {
                Data = new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = "UsersReport.xlsx" }                   
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and its working

```
            return new JsonResult()

            {
                Data = new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = "UsersReport.xlsx" },JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

            };
```